# groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException within Jenkins-Job

Tags: jenkins, groovy

we're using an old groovy-script to generate a pdf for a build-report on our Jenkins-server. The Job did not run for some months but now we reveive the following error altough nothing was changed on the job and at server-side

```
    import hudson.model.*
import hudson.FilePath
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

// make variable bindings available in this script
binding.variables

// Timestamp format for output 
def tsformat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
def to_ts_format = new SimpleDateFormat(tsformat)

// Integrity time format 
def from_integrity_format = new SimpleDateFormat ("MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss aa")

def today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime()

// get current build
def thr = Thread.currentThread()
def build = thr?.executable

// Get parameters 

// reportname must be given as parameter binding - s. Jenkins groovy script extended ("erweitert") settings
String reportname = "${build.envVars.WORKSPACE}"+ "\\" + "${build.envVars.par_reportname}" 

// Get job name from environment 
String srcjobname = "${build.envVars.PAR_JOB}"

// Get from and to
int to = "${build.envVars.PAR_TO}".toInteger ()
int last_to = "${build.envVars.PAR_FROM}".toInteger () 
int from = last_to + 1

// End get parameters 

// Get the job object ... 
def job = Hudson.instance.getJob (srcjobname)

println ("\nCreating report for '"+ job.name + "' builds: " + from + " to " + to + "\n")

// Get job time preceding earliest job in range  
def frompredecessorbuild = job.getNearestOldBuild (last_to)
def predectime
if (frompredecessorbuild != null) {
   println ("\nGot predecessor build: " + frompredecessorbuild.number + ".\n")
   predectime = frompredecessorbuild.getTime ()
} else {
   println ("\nDidn't get predecessor time, no cut off!\n")
   predectime = to_ts_format.parse ("1900-01-01 00:00:00")
}

// Get builds from jobs (alternative way, because getBuildByNumber () seems not to work reliably)
def builds = job.builds

def freport = new FilePath (build.workspace, reportname)
def stream = freport.write()

//
// Create the xml ... 
//
println ("Now create xml.")
try {
  def writer = new StringWriter()
  def xml = new MarkupBuilder(writer)
  xml.changereport (job:srcjobname, time:today.format (tsformat), predecessortime:predectime.format (tsformat)) {
//    for (def i in to .. from) {
    for (def b in builds) {
//      def b = job.getBuildByNumber (i)
        
/*      if (b == null) {
        println ("Skipped build: " + i)
        continue
      } */
      b_no = b.getNumber ()
      if (b_no < from || b_no > to) {
        println ("Skipped build: " + b_no)
        continue
      } else {
        println ("Processing build: " + b_no)
      }

      buildinfo (number:b.number, time:b.getTime ().format (tsformat)) {
        for (cs in b.changeSet) {
          for (ci in cs) {
            citime =  from_integrity_format.parse (ci.date)
            if (citime > predectime) {

              // Add only entries whose date is bigger than the cut-off date
              changeinfo (time:to_ts_format.format (citime), stime:ci.date, action:ci.action, author:ci.getAuthor().getDisplayName()) {
                changedfile (fname:ci.file.toString (), "rev":ci.rev, ci.msg)
              } // changeinfo
            } // if 
          } // for ci ...
        } // for cs ...
      } // buildinfo
    } // for i ...
  } // changereport

} // try 

finally {

  // Need an encoding ... due to umlauts ... 
  stream.write ("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\" standalone=\"yes\"?>".getBytes ())

  stream.write (writer.toString ().getBytes ())
  stream.flush ()
  stream.close ()
}
```

Following error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: writer for class: groovy.lang.Binding
    at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:270)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$7.call(Checker.java:353)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:357)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$checkedGetProperty.callStatic(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallStatic(CallSiteArray.java:56)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:194)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:230)
    at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:123)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runScript(GroovySandbox.java:162)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SecureGroovyScript.evaluate(SecureGroovyScript.java:370)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SecureGroovyScript.evaluate(SecureGroovyScript.java:314)
    at hudson.plugins.groovy.SystemGroovy.run(SystemGroovy.java:95)
    at hudson.plugins.groovy.SystemGroovy.perform(SystemGroovy.java:59)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:741)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:206)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:163)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:504)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1894)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:428)
Build step 'Execute system Groovy script' marked build as failure
```

Something went wrong with the write-object. But we don't know why. Do anybody has a clue for solving the problem?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be declaring your `writer` before the try block if you want to access it in the `finally` block.

```
def writer = null
try {
  writer = new StringWriter()
  def xml = new MarkupBuilder(writer)
  xml.changereport (job:srcjobname, time:today.format (tsformat), predecessortime:predectime.format (tsformat)) {
//    for (def i in to .. from) {
    for (def b in builds) {
//      def b = job.getBuildByNumber (i)
        
/*      if (b == null) {
        println ("Skipped build: " + i)
        continue
      } */
      b_no = b.getNumber ()
      if (b_no < from || b_no > to) {
        println ("Skipped build: " + b_no)
        continue
      } else {
        println ("Processing build: " + b_no)
      }

      buildinfo (number:b.number, time:b.getTime ().format (tsformat)) {
        for (cs in b.changeSet) {
          for (ci in cs) {
            citime =  from_integrity_format.parse (ci.date)
            if (citime > predectime) {

              // Add only entries whose date is bigger than the cut-off date
              changeinfo (time:to_ts_format.format (citime), stime:ci.date, action:ci.action, author:ci.getAuthor().getDisplayName()) {
                changedfile (fname:ci.file.toString (), "rev":ci.rev, ci.msg)
              } // changeinfo
            } // if 
          } // for ci ...
        } // for cs ...
      } // buildinfo
    } // for i ...
  } // changereport

} // try 

finally {

  // Need an encoding ... due to umlauts ... 
  stream.write ("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\" standalone=\"yes\"?>".getBytes ())

  stream.write (writer.toString ().getBytes ())
  stream.flush ()
  stream.close ()
}
```

Comment: thanks, it works! Still wonder, why the error appears now after working a couple of years... nevermind